# Issue with dbConnection, reading in context-params from web.xml

Tags: oracle, jsp, javabeans, ora-01017

i have some jsp code that reads in Servlet Context parameters from a web.xml file. these parameters hold database connection information so each time the SID or user/password or servername changesm, the programmer doesnt have to go re-code; the user can just change the web.xml file.

```
<context-param>
    <description>database user name</description>
    <param-name>user</param-name>
    <param-value>guest</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>database password</description>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>1234</param-value>
</context-param>
```

i read in these using this section of bean class code:

```
String user = servletContext.getInitParameter("user");
String pass = servletContext.getInitParameter("password");
```

The Problem:

next i want to do the database connection to retrieve some data:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_url, user, pass);
```

where conn_url was a string made up of hostname(or ip address) and the port number.

At any rate the dbConnection fails:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

even though i echo out what the String values are and they are what they should be.

if i go and say:

```
user = "guest";
pass = "1234";
```

assigning them directly then it works fine.

I don't get it. Ive rattled my brain all day. Clearly the getConnection looks for 3 Strings. I am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Havr you verified the login details using other software?

Comment: Also, I'd suggest this isn't a good way to handle database config. Opening oracle connections is slow and expensive, you really should use a proper connection pool. You servlet container will have one, and it allows the user/deployter to change the details without messaing with the internals of your web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have done and it is working for me.
i share my code:  in web.xml i wrote like this:

```
 <context-param>
    <description>user name</description>
    <param-name>user</param-name>
    <param-value>postgres</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>password</description>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>samdx</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in Servlet file:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String name = context.getInitParameter("user");
            String password = context.getInitParameter("password");

con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,name, password);
```

try like this. do not get values from web.xml.

```
String name="guest"
String password="1234"
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_url,name, password);
```